# how can i generate more than one avatar?

Tags: html, canvas

as i'm learning how to code and using canvas, i'm doing this project to challenge myself but got this question;
A friend of mine is teaching me how to use canvas, he managed to generate an avatar from a game using its API and we used an input form for the nickname and then drew the avatar below, all fine. BUT I want to draw that same avatar in other parts of the page, while inputting the name only once. is that possible?
[how to generate this avatar more than once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq7eE.png)

The code we're using is as it follows. Thanks in advance o/

```html
 <div id="info">
    <table>
   <tr>
      <td class="left">Habbo Name:</td>
     <td><input oninput="generateAvatar()" id="username" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
  <td class="left">Hotel:</td>
<td>
  <select id="hotel" name="select">
  <option value=".com">.com</option>
 <option value=".com.br" selected>Brazil</option>
 <option value=".fi">Finland</option>
  <option value=".es">Spain</option>
 <option value=".it">Italy</option>
  <option value=".nl">Netherlands</option>
 <option value=".fr">France</option>
 <option value=".de">Germany</option>
  <option value=".tr">Turkey</option>
 </select>
</td>
  </tr> 
  </table>
    

 
<canvas id="User" width="150" height="100"></canvas>    
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("User");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var Head = new Image();  
var Body = new Image(); 
  
function generateAvatar(){
  tUsername = document.getElementById("username").value;
  tHotel = document.getElementById("hotel").value;
  Head.src = "https://www.habbo"+tHotel+"/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user="+tUsername+"&head_direction=3&img_format=gif&gesture=0&headonly=1";
  Body.src = "https://www.habbo"+tHotel+"/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?img_format=gif&user="+tUsername+"&action=std&airection=2&head_direction=2&gesture=sml&size=s";
}
  
Body.onload = function(){
drawAvatar();
};
  
  Head.onload = function(){
drawAvatar();
};
  
  function drawAvatar(){
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Cleans Canvas
    
 var dArr = [-1,-1, 0,-1, 1,-1, -1,0, 1,0, -1,1, 0,1, 1,1], // offset array
      s = 4,  // thickness scale
      i = 0,  // iterator
      x = 0,  // final position
      y = 0;
  
  // draw images at offsets from the array scaled by s
  for(; i < dArr.length; i += 2){
    ctx.drawImage(Head, x + dArr[i]*s, y + dArr[i+1]*s);
    ctx.drawImage(Body, 11 + dArr[i]*s, 15 + dArr[i+1]*s);
  
  // fill with color
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; 
  }
    
    ctx.drawImage(Body, 11, 16);
    ctx.drawImage(Head, 0, 0);
    
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Hello Ines, I think I answered your question correctly below, do you have any questions/comments?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your avatar drawing relative to a set of coordinates...

See my changes to your code below.
I simplified and removed a lot of your code to keep the example short, I would recommend you to do the same when you ask questions, for example you had no problems with your hotel select so remove it and hardcode any value just to focus on the actual problem.
Long code blocks just discourage others from diving into your question.

The key there is `function drawAvatar(x, y, shadow)` now your drawAvatar function takes some parameters and we are no longer doing clearRect inside. There is a new `function draw()` this is the one that clears the canvas will "control" all the drawings.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("User");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var Head = new Image();
Head.onload = draw;

var Body = new Image();
Body.onload = draw;

generateAvatar()

function generateAvatar() {
  tUsername = document.getElementById("username").value;
  Head.src = "https://www.habbo.it/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user=" + tUsername + "&head_direction=3&img_format=gif&gesture=0&headonly=1";
  Body.src = "https://www.habbo.it/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?img_format=gif&user=" + tUsername + "&action=std&airection=2&head_direction=2&gesture=sml&size=s";
}


function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
  drawAvatar(10, 10, 30);
  drawAvatar(80, 15, 10);
  drawAvatar(150, 20, 0);
}

function drawAvatar(x, y, shadow) {
  ctx.shadowColor = 'black';
  ctx.shadowBlur = shadow;
  ctx.drawImage(Body, x + 11, y + 16);
  ctx.drawImage(Head, x, y);
}
```

```html
<input oninput="generateAvatar()" id="username" type="text" value="Mario">
<br/>
<canvas id="User" width="250" height="100"></canvas>
```